Sending JSON Payload from JIRA Webhook to Azure Function App
I have a JIRA webhook set up to send any new issues created to an azure function app. The function app is meant to activate when a new issue is created and take the JSON payload that gets sent from JIRA and grab the information I need using python. I tested the function app and it works, I sent a JSON payload to the URL with the function key included and the python did its job as expected.
My issue now is that when a new issue is created, it does not send the payload to the azure function app, nothing shows in invocations, no logs of any kind to tell me that the JSON payload has attempted to send. I used request bin to see if JIRA is actually sending the payload and it is, I can see a new row in request bin show up when a new issue is created in JIRA.
My question is, when going directly from JIRA to my Azure function app, what can I check to make sure the function app receives the payload, are there any JIRA logs I can view, could there be something I need to check in Azure. Any help on this would be appreciated. Understand this could be a million things but if you've experienced this issue you may be able to point me in the right direction.

I GOT IT WORKING! JIRA cant handle the length of the azure function app URL so I used bitly to shorten the URL and the payload started showing in the function apps invocations. Hope this helps anyone that is struggling with the same problem.
